# The displacement of the elements on the grid with a minimum number of empty cells

Tags: javascript, algorithm, frameworks, logic

Tell me, please, whether there are algorithms or ready solutions for displacing elements inside the grid, so that the elements that have been displaced occupy places on the grid with a minimum number of empty cells.

For example:

It was
[image]

Chosen at 9. The block with 1 decreased to one cell. A block with 9 increased to six cells.

It is necessary to scatter the elements that were expelled from the vacant places.

[image]

Comment: It's not that easy... https://jsfiddle.net/pkonm9g6/ (simple attempt failed, but maybe someone can improve it)

Comment: There might be some problems with this layout if you want to keep the order of the elements. If you click on 1 and then on 5 in the jsFiddle you will notice how the 5 is in the correct position, but it jumped from right to left.

Comment: Maraca, thanks for trying. I myself also did not understand how to solve it.

Comment: If you position absolute with js then it's possible, I tried to make a CSS based version where all you do is add and remove the selected class. But you have to be a CSS wizard to pull that off, if it is possible.

Comment: Do you want to maintain the order of the elements?

Comment: Yes. If possible, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My version of the solution through pre-written states:

```js
/* Получение состояния в которое необходимо перейти  */
function getTransition(state, selected) {
    /* Переходы */
    var transition = {
        /* Текущие состояние */
        1: {
            /* В какое состояние перейти */
            autohydraulic: 1,
            onboardcars: 2,
            sleepcabins: 10,
            dumpers: 3,
            airports: 9,
            trailers: 4,
            cranes: 5,
            tugboats: 6,
            firetrucks: 7,
            doublerowcabins: 8
        },
        2: {
            autohydraulic: 1,
            onboardcars: 2,
            sleepcabins: 10,
            dumpers: 11,
            airports: 9,
            trailers: 12,
            cranes: 5,
            tugboats: 6,
            firetrucks: 7,
            doublerowcabins: 8
        },
        3: {
            autohydraulic: 1,
            onboardcars: 13,
            sleepcabins: 10,
            dumpers: 3,
            airports: 9,
            trailers: 12,
            cranes: 5,
            tugboats: 6,
            firetrucks: 7,
            doublerowcabins: 8
        },
        4: {
            autohydraulic: 1,
            onboardcars: 2,
            sleepcabins: 10,
            dumpers: 11,
            airports: 9,
            trailers: 4,
            cranes: 5,
            tugboats: 14,
            firetrucks: 15,
            doublerowcabins: 8
        },
        5: {
            autohydraulic: 1,
            onboardcars: 2,
            sleepcabins: 10,
            dumpers: 3,
            airports: 9,
            trailers: 4,
            cranes: 5,
            tugboats: 16,
            firetrucks: 7,
            doublerowcabins: 8
        },
        6: {
            autohydraulic: 1,
            onboardcars: 2,
            sleepcabins: 10,
            dumpers: 11,
            airports: 9,
            trailers: 12,
            cranes: 5,
            tugboats: 6,
            firetrucks: 15,
            doublerowcabins: 8
        },
        7: {
            autohydraulic: 1,
            onboardcars: 2,
            sleepcabins: 10,
            dumpers: 11,
            airports: 9,
            trailers: 12,
            cranes: 5,
            tugboats: 16,
            firetrucks: 7,
            doublerowcabins: 8
        },
        8: {
            autohydraulic: 1,
            onboardcars: 2,
            sleepcabins: 10,
            dumpers: 11,
            airports: 17,
            trailers: 12,
            cranes: 5,
            tugboats: 6,
            firetrucks: 15,
            doublerowcabins: 8
        },
        9: {
            autohydraulic: 1,
            onboardcars: 2,
            sleepcabins: 10,
            dumpers: 11,
            airports: 9,
            trailers: 12,
            cranes: 5,
            tugboats: 16,
            firetrucks: 15,
            doublerowcabins: 18
        },
        10: {
            autohydraulic: 1,
            onboardcars: 2,
            sleepcabins: 10,
            dumpers: 11,
            airports: 17,
            trailers: 12,
            cranes: 5,
            tugboats: 6,
            firetrucks: 7,
            doublerowcabins: 8
        },
        11: {
            autohydraulic: 19,
            onboardcars: 2,
            sleepcabins: 10,
            dumpers: 11,
            airports: 9,
            trailers: 4,
            cranes: 5,
            tugboats: 6,
            firetrucks: 7,
            doublerowcabins: 8
        },
        12: {
            autohydraulic: 1,
            onboardcars: 2,
            sleepcabins: 10,
            dumpers: 3,
            airports: 9,
            trailers: 12,
            cranes: 20,
            tugboats: 16,
            firetrucks: 7,
            doublerowcabins: 8
        },
        13: {
            autohydraulic: 19,
            onboardcars: 13,
            sleepcabins: 10,
            dumpers: 3,
            airports: 9,
            trailers: 4,
            cranes: 5,
            tugboats: 6,
            firetrucks: 7,
            doublerowcabins: 8
        },
        14: {
            autohydraulic: 1,
            onboardcars: 2,
            sleepcabins: 10,
            dumpers: 3,
            airports: 9,
            trailers: 4,
            cranes: 20,
            tugboats: 14,
            firetrucks: 7,
            doublerowcabins: 8
        },
        15: {
            autohydraulic: 1,
            onboardcars: 21,
            sleepcabins: 10,
            dumpers: 11,
            airports: 9,
            trailers: 12,
            cranes: 5,
            tugboats: 6,
            firetrucks: 15,
            doublerowcabins: 8
        },
        16: {
            autohydraulic: 1,
            onboardcars: 21,
            sleepcabins: 10,
            dumpers: 11,
            airports: 9,
            trailers: 12,
            cranes: 5,
            tugboats: 16,
            firetrucks: 7,
            doublerowcabins: 8
        },
        17: {
            autohydraulic: 1,
            onboardcars: 2,
            sleepcabins: 10,
            dumpers: 11,
            airports: 17,
            trailers: 12,
            cranes: 5,
            tugboats: 16,
            firetrucks: 22,
            doublerowcabins: 8
        },
        18: {
            autohydraulic: 1,
            onboardcars: 2,
            sleepcabins: 10,
            dumpers: 11,
            airports: 9,
            trailers: 12,
            cranes: 5,
            tugboats: 16,
            firetrucks: 22,
            doublerowcabins: 18
        },
        19: {
            autohydraulic: 19,
            onboardcars: 13,
            sleepcabins: 10,
            dumpers: 11,
            airports: 9,
            trailers: 12,
            cranes: 5,
            tugboats: 6,
            firetrucks: 7,
            doublerowcabins: 8
        },
        20: {
            autohydraulic: 1,
            onboardcars: 21,
            sleepcabins: 10,
            dumpers: 11,
            airports: 9,
            trailers: 12,
            cranes: 20,
            tugboats: 6,
            firetrucks: 7,
            doublerowcabins: 8
        },
        21: {
            autohydraulic: 1,
            onboardcars: 21,
            sleepcabins: 10,
            dumpers: 3,
            airports: 9,
            trailers: 4,
            cranes: 20,
            tugboats: 16,
            firetrucks: 7,
            doublerowcabins: 8
        },
        22: {
            autohydraulic: 1,
            onboardcars: 2,
            sleepcabins: 23,
            dumpers: 11,
            airports: 17,
            trailers: 12,
            cranes: 5,
            tugboats: 6,
            firetrucks: 22,
            doublerowcabins: 8
        },
        23: {
            autohydraulic: 1,
            onboardcars: 2,
            sleepcabins: 23,
            dumpers: 11,
            airports: 9,
            trailers: 12,
            cranes: 5,
            tugboats: 16,
            firetrucks: 22,
            doublerowcabins: 8
        }
    };

    return transition[state][selected];
}

/* Получение конкретного состояния по его идентификатору */
function getStatesByItem(id) {
    /* Состояния элементов при выбранном активном элементе */
    var states = {
        /* Порядковые номера для состояний */
        1: {
            autohydraulic: 'row-1 col-1',
            onboardcars: 'row-1 col-3',
            sleepcabins: 'row-1 col-4',
            dumpers: 'row-2 col-3',
            airports: 'row-2 col-4',
            trailers: 'row-3 col-3',
            cranes: 'row-4 col-1',
            tugboats: 'row-4 col-2',
            firetrucks: 'row-4 col-3',
            doublerowcabins: 'row-4 col-4'
        },
        2: {
            autohydraulic: 'row-1 col-1',
            onboardcars: 'row-1 col-2',
            sleepcabins: 'row-1 col-4',
            dumpers: 'row-2 col-1',
            airports: 'row-2 col-4',
            trailers: 'row-3 col-1',
            cranes: 'row-4 col-1',
            tugboats: 'row-4 col-2',
            firetrucks: 'row-4 col-3',
            doublerowcabins: 'row-4 col-4'
        },
        3: {
            autohydraulic: 'row-1 col-1',
            onboardcars: 'row-2 col-1',
            sleepcabins: 'row-1 col-4',
            dumpers: 'row-1 col-2',
            airports: 'row-2 col-4',
            trailers: 'row-3 col-1',
            cranes: 'row-4 col-1',
            tugboats: 'row-4 col-2',
            firetrucks: 'row-4 col-3',
            doublerowcabins: 'row-4 col-4'
        },
        4: {
            autohydraulic: 'row-1 col-1',
            onboardcars: 'row-1 col-3',
            sleepcabins: 'row-1 col-4',
            dumpers: 'row-2 col-1',
            airports: 'row-2 col-4',
            trailers: 'row-2 col-2',
            cranes: 'row-4 col-1',
            tugboats: 'row-3 col-1',
            firetrucks: 'row-1 col-2',
            doublerowcabins: 'row-4 col-4'
        },
        5: {
            autohydraulic: 'row-1 col-1',
            onboardcars: 'row-1 col-3',
            sleepcabins: 'row-1 col-4',
            dumpers: 'row-2 col-3',
            airports: 'row-2 col-4',
            trailers: 'row-3 col-3',
            cranes: 'row-2 col-1',
            tugboats: 'row-1 col-2',
            firetrucks: 'row-4 col-3',
            doublerowcabins: 'row-4 col-4'
        },
        6: {
            autohydraulic: 'row-1 col-1',
            onboardcars: 'row-1 col-3',
            sleepcabins: 'row-1 col-4',
            dumpers: 'row-2 col-1',
            airports: 'row-2 col-4',
            trailers: 'row-3 col-1',
            cranes: 'row-4 col-1',
            tugboats: 'row-2 col-2',
            firetrucks: 'row-1 col-2',
            doublerowcabins: 'row-4 col-4'
        },
        7: {
            autohydraulic: 'row-1 col-1',
            onboardcars: 'row-1 col-3',
            sleepcabins: 'row-1 col-4',
            dumpers: 'row-2 col-1',
            airports: 'row-2 col-4',
            trailers: 'row-3 col-1',
            cranes: 'row-4 col-1',
            tugboats: 'row-1 col-2',
            firetrucks: 'row-2 col-2',
            doublerowcabins: 'row-4 col-4'
        },
        8: {
            autohydraulic: 'row-1 col-1',
            onboardcars: 'row-1 col-3',
            sleepcabins: 'row-1 col-4',
            dumpers: 'row-2 col-1',
            airports: 'row-2 col-2',
            trailers: 'row-3 col-1',
            cranes: 'row-4 col-1',
            tugboats: 'row-4 col-2',
            firetrucks: 'row-1 col-2',
            doublerowcabins: 'row-2 col-3'
        },
        9: {
            autohydraulic: 'row-1 col-1',
            onboardcars: 'row-1 col-3',
            sleepcabins: 'row-1 col-4',
            dumpers: 'row-2 col-1',
            airports: 'row-2 col-3',
            trailers: 'row-3 col-1',
            cranes: 'row-4 col-1',
            tugboats: 'row-2 col-2',
            firetrucks: 'row-1 col-2',
            doublerowcabins: 'row-3 col-2'
        },
        10: {
            autohydraulic: 'row-1 col-1',
            onboardcars: 'row-1 col-2',
            sleepcabins: 'row-1 col-3',
            dumpers: 'row-2 col-1',
            airports: 'row-2 col-2',
            trailers: 'row-3 col-1',
            cranes: 'row-4 col-1',
            tugboats: 'row-4 col-2',
            firetrucks: 'row-4 col-3',
            doublerowcabins: 'row-4 col-4'
        },
        11: {
            autohydraulic: 'row-2 col-3',
            onboardcars: 'row-1 col-3',
            sleepcabins: 'row-1 col-4',
            dumpers: 'row-1 col-1',
            airports: 'row-2 col-4',
            trailers: 'row-3 col-3',
            cranes: 'row-4 col-1',
            tugboats: 'row-4 col-2',
            firetrucks: 'row-4 col-3',
            doublerowcabins: 'row-4 col-4'
        },
        12: {
            autohydraulic: 'row-1 col-1',
            onboardcars: 'row-1 col-3',
            sleepcabins: 'row-1 col-4',
            dumpers: 'row-2 col-3',
            airports: 'row-2 col-4',
            trailers: 'row-2 col-1',
            cranes: 'row-3 col-3',
            tugboats: 'row-1 col-2',
            firetrucks: 'row-4 col-3',
            doublerowcabins: 'row-4 col-4'
        },
        13: {
            autohydraulic: 'row-1 col-3',
            onboardcars: 'row-1 col-1',
            sleepcabins: 'row-1 col-4',
            dumpers: 'row-2 col-3',
            airports: 'row-2 col-4',
            trailers: 'row-3 col-3',
            cranes: 'row-4 col-1',
            tugboats: 'row-4 col-2',
            firetrucks: 'row-4 col-3',
            doublerowcabins: 'row-4 col-4'
        },
        14: {
            autohydraulic: 'row-1 col-1',
            onboardcars: 'row-1 col-3',
            sleepcabins: 'row-1 col-4',
            dumpers: 'row-2 col-3',
            airports: 'row-2 col-4',
            trailers: 'row-3 col-3',
            cranes: 'row-1 col-2',
            tugboats: 'row-2 col-1',
            firetrucks: 'row-4 col-3',
            doublerowcabins: 'row-4 col-4'
        },
        15: {
            autohydraulic: 'row-1 col-1',
            onboardcars: 'row-4 col-2',
            sleepcabins: 'row-1 col-4',
            dumpers: 'row-2 col-1',
            airports: 'row-2 col-4',
            trailers: 'row-3 col-1',
            cranes: 'row-4 col-1',
            tugboats: 'row-4 col-3',
            firetrucks: 'row-1 col-2',
            doublerowcabins: 'row-4 col-4'
        },
        16: {
            autohydraulic: 'row-1 col-1',
            onboardcars: 'row-4 col-2',
            sleepcabins: 'row-1 col-4',
            dumpers: 'row-2 col-1',
            airports: 'row-2 col-4',
            trailers: 'row-3 col-1',
            cranes: 'row-4 col-1',
            tugboats: 'row-1 col-2',
            firetrucks: 'row-4 col-3',
            doublerowcabins: 'row-4 col-4'
        },
        17: {
            autohydraulic: 'row-1 col-1',
            onboardcars: 'row-1 col-3',
            sleepcabins: 'row-1 col-4',
            dumpers: 'row-2 col-1',
            airports: 'row-2 col-2',
            trailers: 'row-3 col-1',
            cranes: 'row-4 col-1',
            tugboats: 'row-1 col-2',
            firetrucks: 'row-2 col-4',
            doublerowcabins: 'row-3 col-4'
        },
        18: {
            autohydraulic: 'row-1 col-1',
            onboardcars: 'row-1 col-3',
            sleepcabins: 'row-1 col-4',
            dumpers: 'row-2 col-1',
            airports: 'row-3 col-4',
            trailers: 'row-3 col-1',
            cranes: 'row-4 col-1',
            tugboats: 'row-1 col-2',
            firetrucks: 'row-2 col-4',
            doublerowcabins: 'row-2 col-2'
        },
        19: {
            autohydraulic: 'row-1 col-2',
            onboardcars: 'row-1 col-1',
            sleepcabins: 'row-1 col-4',
            dumpers: 'row-2 col-1',
            airports: 'row-2 col-4',
            trailers: 'row-3 col-1',
            cranes: 'row-4 col-1',
            tugboats: 'row-4 col-2',
            firetrucks: 'row-4 col-3',
            doublerowcabins: 'row-4 col-4'
        },
        20: {
            autohydraulic: 'row-1 col-1',
            onboardcars: 'row-4 col-1',
            sleepcabins: 'row-1 col-4',
            dumpers: 'row-2 col-1',
            airports: 'row-2 col-4',
            trailers: 'row-3 col-1',
            cranes: 'row-1 col-2',
            tugboats: 'row-4 col-2',
            firetrucks: 'row-4 col-3',
            doublerowcabins: 'row-4 col-4'
        },
        21: {
            autohydraulic: 'row-1 col-1',
            onboardcars: 'row-2 col-1',
            sleepcabins: 'row-1 col-4',
            dumpers: 'row-2 col-3',
            airports: 'row-2 col-4',
            trailers: 'row-3 col-3',
            cranes: 'row-1 col-2',
            tugboats: 'row-1 col-3',
            firetrucks: 'row-4 col-3',
            doublerowcabins: 'row-4 col-4'
        },
        22: {
            autohydraulic: 'row-1 col-1',
            onboardcars: 'row-1 col-2',
            sleepcabins: 'row-4 col-2',
            dumpers: 'row-2 col-1',
            airports: 'row-2 col-2',
            trailers: 'row-3 col-1',
            cranes: 'row-4 col-1',
            tugboats: 'row-4 col-3',
            firetrucks: 'row-1 col-3',
            doublerowcabins: 'row-4 col-4'
        },
        23: {
            autohydraulic: 'row-1 col-1',
            onboardcars: 'row-1 col-3',
            sleepcabins: 'row-2 col-2',
            dumpers: 'row-2 col-1',
            airports: 'row-2 col-4',
            trailers: 'row-3 col-1',
            cranes: 'row-4 col-1',
            tugboats: 'row-1 col-2',
            firetrucks: 'row-1 col-4',
            doublerowcabins: 'row-4 col-4'
        }
    };
    return states[id];
}

/* Установка состояний элементов по конкретному элементу  */
function setStatesByItem(coord) {
    for (var key in coord) {
        if (coord.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            jQuery('#' + key).addClass(coord[key]);
        }
    }
}

/* Функция, которая выполняется на месте её вызова */
(function (jQuery)
{
    /* Прототоп jQuery для уменьшения элементов */
    jQuery.fn.elementsToSmall = function () {
        this.each(function () {
            jQuery(this).removeClass('big');
        });
    };

    /* Прототоп jQuery для увеличения элемента */
    jQuery.fn.elementToBig = function () {
        jQuery(this).addClass('big');
    };

    /* Прототоп jQuery для установки позиций элементов */
    jQuery.fn.setPosition = function (state) {
        jQuery('.box').each(function () {

            /* Сбросить текущие координаты по строкам */
            jQuery(this).removeClass(function (index, className) {
                return (className.match(/(^|\s)row-\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
            });

            /* Сбросить текущие координаты по столбцам */
            jQuery(this).removeClass(function (index, className) {
                return (className.match(/(^|\s)col-\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
            });
        });

        /* Получить новые координаты элементов по текущему состоянию */
        var coordinates = getStatesByItem(state);

        /* Установить новые координаты */
        setStatesByItem(coordinates);

    };
})(jQuery);

/* Работаем с данными после того, как структура страницы сформирована */
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    /* Текущее состояние по умолчанию */
    var state = 1;

    /* Обработчики элементам с классом box при наведении */
    jQuery('.box').mouseenter(function () {

        /* Получить идентификаторы выбранного элемента */
        var selectedItem = jQuery(this).attr('id');

        /* Получаем состояние в которое необходимо перейти */
        state = getTransition(state, selectedItem);

        /* Уменьшаем все элементы кроме текущего */
        jQuery('.box').not(this).elementsToSmall();

        /* Увеличиваем текущий элемент */
        jQuery(this).elementToBig();

        /* Устанавливаем элементам положение на сетке */
        jQuery(this).setPosition(state);

    });

});
```

```css
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman';
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}
.text {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  text-align: center;
}
.center {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.containerbox {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  width: 800px;
  height: 480px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.containerbox .box {
  display: table;
  width: 198px;
  height: 118px;
  background-color: #cfe7f5;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  font-size: 4rem;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 5;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.containerbox .box.merge-col {
  height: 238px;
}
.containerbox .box.col-not {
  left: -400px;
}
.containerbox .box.col-1 {
  left: 0;
}
.containerbox .box.col-2 {
  left: 200px;
}
.containerbox .box.col-3 {
  left: 400px;
}
.containerbox .box.col-4 {
  left: 600px;
}
.containerbox .box.row-not {
  top: -360px;
}
.containerbox .box.row-1 {
  top: 0;
}
.containerbox .box.row-2 {
  top: 120px;
}
.containerbox .box.row-3 {
  top: 240px;
}
.containerbox .box.row-4 {
  top: 360px;
}
.containerbox .box.big {
  width: 398px;
  height: 358px;
  background-color: #83caff;
  z-index: 10;
}
.containerbox .description {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/grid.js"></script>
        <title>Меню из изображений для сайта</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="containerbox">
                <div id="autohydraulic" class="box big row-1 col-1">
                    <span class="description">1</span>
                </div>
                <div id="onboardcars" class="box row-1 col-3">
                    <span class="description">2</span>
                </div>
                <div id="sleepcabins" class="box row-1 col-4">
                    <span class="description">3</span>
                </div>
                <div id="dumpers" class="box row-2 col-3">
                    <span class="description">4</span>
                </div>
                <div id="airports" class="box merge-col row-2 col-4">
                    <span class="description">5</span>
                </div>
                <div id="trailers" class="box row-3 col-3">
                    <span class="description">6</span>
                </div>
                <div id="cranes" class="box row-4 col-1">
                    <span class="description">7</span>
                </div>
                <div id="tugboats" class="box row-4 col-2">
                    <span class="description">8</span>
                </div>
                <div id="firetrucks" class="box row-4 col-3">
                    <span class="description">9</span>
                </div>
                <div id="doublerowcabins" class="box row-4 col-4">
                    <span class="description">10</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/devnn/xaukLsgj/2/